# jquery File not applying to webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been building a new website recently and experimenting a lot with jQuery.

Unfortunately I seem to be having a massive problem getting my jquery file to actually work in the website.

Here is the html code. As you can see, I have jquery added by CDN and the javascript is in a totally separate file. I added an alert into the primary function just to check if it's even reading what I have put and I am stuck.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Browser Data-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--Meta Data -->
        <title>website</title>
        <meta name="description" content="The Official Page of website">
        <meta name="Keywords" content="some website stuff">
        <meta name="author" content="me">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <!-- CSS File Locations -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!-- Javascript File Locations -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Fonts used -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Germania+One" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- A logo will go here but here is some text for now -->
        <H1 ID="Logo">website</H1>

        <!-- The menu bar -->
        <ul class="menu" ID="Menu_Bar">
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Home">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="About_Us">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Events">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Contact">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- An image of the stuff-->
        <img ID="theGang" src="assets/thegang.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#theGang").fadeIn(3000);
        alert("it worked");
    });
});
```

I'm just not sure why it's not working.

By the way the javascript file is in a sub folder called js and called main.js and the html is called index.html

Comment: For starters, you don't have any `button` elements, so how is it supposed to work ?

Comment: Where's your `button` ?

Comment: The idea is that the ID "theGang" will fadein, I thought the alert would simply start once the page loaded

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're saying, I'm a twat hahaha sorry about that guys, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: I have now changed the jquery so it now says the code without the button, the alert is happening but the fade is not

Comment: You can't fade in something that is already visible. Did you set the image to `display:none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like all you needed to do was remove the event handler for the nonexistent `button` element.  This enables the fadeIn and alert.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#theGang").fadeIn(3000);
      //alert("it worked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- A logo will go here but here is some text for now -->
        <H1 ID="Logo">website</H1>

        <!-- The menu bar -->
        <ul class="menu" ID="Menu_Bar">
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Home">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="About_Us">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Events">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li Class="Menu_Item" ID="Contact">
                <a Class="Menu_Link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- An image of the stuff-->
        <img ID="theGang" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/cute-cat-picture_1122-449.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
```

Comment: So I have removed the button tag but it's still not fading in the image. Have a added the reference to the jquery library correctly?

Comment: I've edited my answer such that the image now fades in.  All that was necessary is to add `style="display: none;"` to the image to make the `fadeIn` work.

Comment: PERFECT, I never thought that the CSS would affect a simple fade in effect!